# How to fix F# error FS0193: FSharp.Core does not contain ValLinkagePartialKey (F#)?

Tags: f#, suave

I am doing the F# SuaveMusicStore tutorial of theimowski and ran into the following error:

```
error FS0193: The module/namespace 'Control' from compilation unit 'FSharp.Core' did not contain the val 'ValLinkagePartialKey(OnSuccess)'
```

It seems to come up when I use the WebPart `succeed`. It seems weird that the error occurs in FSharp.Core while `succeed` is a WebPart that comes from the Suave package.

I have tried plenty of things: Down- and upgraded my FSharp.Core package which resulted in other FS0193 errors, and I searched for alternatives to `succeed`.

Anyone has a solution to this problem?

Comment: You need to be more specific about your problem. What did you try? Can you show us some code? Please [read how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question to improve it. Thank you!

Comment: Which FSharp.Core version are you using? Do you have binding redirects in app.config?

Comment: got the same error, trying to convert an old f# project, which references an C# wpf library net5.0-windows. So I guess FSharp.Core should be implicitely 5.0